# Visual Studio 2017: Why am I getting "user-defined literal operator not found" error in C++ code?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I wrote a C++ code like this:

```
#define BUILDNUM "DEBUG"
#define PROGRAMNAME "Some text " ## BUILDNUM
const char ProgramName[] = {PROGRAMNAME};
```

and getting "user-defined literal operator not found" error while compiling. I know that the literal operator which is causing the grief is `BUILDNUM` because when I comment out `//## BUILDNUM` the code compiles no problem. The interesting thing is that this code was compiling before. I did some changes in unrelated files and it doesn't compile anymore.

What is the problem? I don't seem to find what is causing it.

Comment: Looks like an IntelliSense parser problem, compiles just fine.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks. I did that. Let's see what they say. I am a novice with VS and my first impression is that it is not very consistent.

Comment: `"Some text " ## BUILDNUM` forms an invalid token `"Some text "BUILDNUM`, not `"Some text ""DEBUG"` as you might expect. This exhibits undefined behavior. Just make it `#define PROGRAMNAME "Some text "  BUILDNUM` (without `##`) and rely on automatic string literal concatenation.

Comment: @HansPassant I believe it compiles only because MSVC has a non-conforming preprocessor, one that operates on a stream of characters rather than a stream of tokens. At least in previous versions, this failed: `#define N -1` and then `-N;`, since it was interpreted as `--1` rather than `- -1` aka  `-(-1)`

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Why? I am doing it according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09dwwt6y.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. I also noticed when I don't have a window open of the file in question in VS the code compiles. Something weird is going on.

Comment: Token-pasting happens before further macro expansion. You paste together token `"Some text "` and token `BUILDNUM` (*not* `"DEBUG"`), producing a sequence of characters `"Some text "BUILDNUM` that is not a valid preprocessing token, triggering [undefined behavior](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.concat#3). "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. However, both GCC and Clang report an error on your example.

Comment: I have similar issue with this macro:

    #define SOUND_UI(__name__) ("snd/ui/ogg/"__name__".ogg")